# Time travel movie with a loser watching an apple rot, and there are moon people

Tags: identify-this-movie, time-travel

I'm trying to find a movie which I watched around 2008-2009 winter with the following details:

- The story starts 50-200 years before today. There is no electronic devices around.
- The protagonist was a middle aged man who is very knowledge about mechanical devices; specifically on about something that I can't remember. Maybe about clocks.
- He works many years on the time machine. People around him say that he is wasting his life, he is a loser in life.
- He uses a special part as the core of the machine, which I totally don't remember.
- The time traveling device was consisting of metallic frames. I think it had a spherical geometry. There was a seat at the center of it. I remember some parts of it rotating once it is activated. Lots of warm white light come out of it just before the time travel.
- During the time travel, the device doesn't change physical location; it stays in a fixed point. When you are traveling to future, you see objects around you aging fast. Maybe there was a scene which shows a rotting apple or something like that.
- The man travels to a very far future. Where the Moon was partially destroyed (may be not). Some people immigrated to Moon. Remaining ones are living like cavemen. The protagonist arrives to a valley among high mountains. Soon people come out of caves on those mountains and introduce with him. He helps those people greatly by solving a big problem of theirs.
- I remember him traveling an even further future; maybe 1.000.000 years after our time.

Comment: The moon falling apart with red cracks is indeed memorable....very sad and tragic in a way.

Comment: I'd hardly call him a loser, he invented time travel!

Comment: @Cage: I didn't call him so. Somebody edited my message so, and someone other approved it.

Comment: Ah ok. Strange thing to add to someones question,  somebody must have been having an off day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds very much like a description of *H.G. Wells*' [*The Time Machine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine).

It has been adapted to film more than once, but the two most famous ones are from [1960](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054387/) (which I haven't seen yet though) and from [2002](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268695/), which I have seen and know that it invloves a partially destroyed moon at some point in the future. And given that you didn't say the movie itself was significantly old (and the effects you describe), this seems like a good fit:

> Based on the classic sci-fi novel by H.G. Wells, scientist and inventor, Alexander Hartdegen, is determined to prove that time travel is possible. His determination is turned to desperation by a personal tragedy that now drives him to want to change the past. Testing his theories with a time machine of his own invention, Hartdegen is hurtled 800,000 years into the future, where he discovers that mankind has divided into the hunter - and the hunted.

Comment: I believe the 1960 version involves him briefly experiencing a nuclear attack (when he stops in the 1960s; when the sirens go off he is admonished to seek shelter before the "shrooms start sprouting").  There is no moon destroyed in this version.